# Connecting Win7 to Win7 through switches, EnGenius, and Routers

Tags: networking, switch

Weird networks, causing weird problems. I am a new employee at this company, the network is a bit weird, but I have figured it out to a degree. I have some networking knowledge, but not greatly versed.

I have a Windows 7 machine in the front office. It is setup for serving some network drives, and some software. Quickbooks, Wasp Barcode System, etc.

I have a computer connected to the switch in the second building that I am trying to connect the the Windows 7 (Server) in the front office.

I am unable to do so. I keep getting Network Path errors, I have turned Ping echo on the "Server" but do not receive responses. I can see it when I look at the Network in Explorer, but cannot open it (Error Code 0x80070035 The network path was not found). I have checked the sharing settings on both computers, they are ok (see attached). Firewall is disabled on the "Server". I am attaching a quick diagram that I drew up.

I can ping the server from the front office. I can also view the shared drive from the "Server" from my main machine in the front office. I am on the same switch at that time.

I can provide more info if needed.

Any Suggestions?

## Sharing Settings:

[image]

## Network Diagram:

[image]

Comment: What are the devices labelled "ENG", "CB", and "AP"?

Comment: Sorry for that. ENG is an EnGenius indoor connecter, it connects the actual device, AP (Access Point) or CB (Client Bridge), to the Switches.

The actual devices are EnGenius ENH202's there are 3 of them.

Comment: Can anything in the second building ping anything else in the front office? Do your switches or EnGenius devices have IP addresses that can be pinged?

Comment: No, which made me wonder if the switch was a problem.

Comment: If you can't ping across the links from anything to anything then that points to the EnGenius stuff not connecting correctly. Can users in the other two bulidings get to the internet?

Comment: they have full internet access, just cannot connect to computers on the main office switch.

Comment: Then it's not the EnGenius gear causing the problem. Can you ping something at building 1 or 2 *from the server* in question? If not then it might be a routing problem. If you can ping from the server, double check any firewall software on the server. Is the server running any anti-virus? A/V these days often has a built-in firewall that is not obviously a firewall.

Comment: Just attempted... failed, Destination host unreachable.

Comment: Is everything on the same IP range or does each building have its own IP space? If the latter, then it sounds like the server might not be able to get a route to the other buildings, even though the other buildings can route to the front office and Internet.

Comment: same ip range. Server is 192.168.0.83, W7 in second building is 192.168.0.55

Comment: Do the devices that connect the offices pass Layer 2 broadcast traffic? One of the indications of `Destination host unreachable` would be that the ARP request from the source machine isn't being answered, possibly because ARP broadcasts are blocked by the devices connecting the offices.

Comment: Referring to web browser traffic? I can connect to the primary router (main office) via web browser from the building 1 computer that I have been having trouble with. I also have full internet access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had something similar dealing with a client site with a DDWRT'd router a while back and found this:
http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode#routed_client_mode

From the above page:

Masqueraded - "Using masquerading (NAT) on a client router connects a network segment behind the client to an existing wireless network without further modifications to the access point. The downside is that hosts on the AP side cannot access hosts behind the client router. "

Routed - "This option requires a static route on the AP pointing to the subnet behind the client router using the client router's IP on the AP network as a gateway. This allows hosts on both segments to reach each other directly, but it requires administrative access to the AP in order to configure the static route. "

Yours is sounding a lot like the "Masqueraded" option, where you'd be wanting the "Routed" option.

I'm not sure how exactly to do that in the EnGenius software, but a quick look through the user manual makes me think that's what it does by default.